# How to get the device settings of time format (24/12 hour) on iOS/Xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I need to access the device settings of an iOS device from code and get the settings that specifies if the time is displayed as 12hour or 24hour format. I could use the "NSLocale.CurrentLocale" property but that just has the default time format of given locale, not the device settings, doesn't it?
I haven't found and related info online, so I'm asking for help here.

Comment: The documentation seems clear. Isn't it? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslocale/1409990-currentlocale

Comment: Ok, then it might reflect the 24/12 format, but still, I don't see the property to check what format is used. I need to get something like bool Use24HourFormat = (check if 24 hour format is set).

Answer (score 6):

Try this code for iOS:

```
private bool CheckIsTwelveTimeFormat()
{
    var dateFormatter = new NSDateFormatter();
    dateFormatter.DateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.None;
    dateFormatter.TimeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.Short;

    var dateString = dateFormatter.ToString(NSDate.Now);
    var isTwelveHourFormat = 
    dateString.Contains(dateFormatter.AMSymbol) || 
    dateString.Contains(dateFormatter.PMSymbol);
    return isTwelveHourFormat;
}
```

And this for android:

```
private bool CheckIsTwelveTimeFormat()
{
    return Android.Text.Format.DateFormat.Is24HourFormat(Android.App.Application.Context);
}
```